# Nginx / Uwsgi cache configuration

Tags: nginx, cache, uwsgi

I have the following Nginx cache `site.conf` file:

```
uwsgi_cache_path /home/ubuntu/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:10m;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name genelizleyici.com;

    location /api/tweets/ {
        uwsgi_cache one;
        uwsgi_cache_valid any 1m;
        uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/ubuntu/uwsgi.socket;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_cache one;
        uwsgi_cache_valid any 1m;
        uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/ubuntu/uwsgi.socket;
    }

}
```

It is working fine for the `/api/tweets/` and the json responses are cached but the home page, (i.e. '/') is not cached.

The cache configurations are equivalent. The only difference I can think of between these two is that, the responses of the first are `json`.

Any ideas why the cache configuration for `/` not taken into account? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working fine for the home page? Please edit your question to answer.

Comment: home page is not cached while the api responses are cached. i updated the question.